# timezone en laravel es incorrecta

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo configurado mi timezone en app/config

```
'timezone' => 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
```

cuando guardo un registro en la db se guarda bien

```
2022-06-13 20:32:27
```

y cuando retorno al front la zona horaria es incorrecta, le suma horas

```
13-06-2022 23:32:27
```

porque sucede esto? ya limpie la cache y configure la cache nuevamente

Comment: Revisa el timezone de un `phpinfo()` y desde php el resultado de la consulta `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;`.

Comment: SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone; ME ARROJA, SYSTEM EN CADA COLUMNA